# How to load plist and pass string Array polygons under NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to load data.plist string array polygons under NSDictionary(ex. +40.48675,-60.434543) to building. I have 6 index in array. I keep getting warning "Passing argument 7 of initWithID:name:code:number:location:description:polygons from incompatible pointer type."
Also the draw polygon doesnt show on map. What ami I missing?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];   
NSArray *array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] objectAtIndex:0];

buildings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *buildingID = [dic objectForKey:@"buildingID"];
    NSString *name = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *code = [dic objectForKey:@"code"];
    NSString *number = [dic objectForKey:@"number"];
    //NSString *location = [dic objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSString *description = [dic objectForKey:@"description"];
    //NSArray *components = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //NSString *latitude = [components objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSString *longitude = [components objectAtIndex:1];

    NSArray *polygons = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    polygons = [dic objectForKey:@"polygons"];

    int countPoints = [self.polygons count];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D buildingPoly[countPoints];

    for (int i = 0; i < countPoints; i++) {
        NSArray *splitArrayPoly = [[polygons objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        buildingPoly[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[splitArrayPoly objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[splitArrayPoly objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
    }       


    NSArray *splitArray = [ [dic objectForKey:@"location"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    float latitude = [[splitArray objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
    float longitude = [[splitArray objectAtIndex:1]floatValue];

    CLLocation *tempLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc]
                                 initWithLatitude:latitude 
                                 longitude:longitude]autorelease];

    Building *building = [[[Building alloc] initWithID:[buildingID intValue] 
                                                  name:name 
                                                  code:code 
                                                number:number 
                                              location:tempLocation 
                                           description:description
                                              polygons:buildingPoly]autorelease]; //This is where I got warning
    //building.polygons = polygons; // delete this when ure done with init
    //NSLog(@"building.polygons = %@", building.polygons); // ask teacher about this
    [buildings addObject:building];

    [dic release];
    [building release];

}
```

Then in different class "Building.m" it pass polygons to here

```
- (id)initWithID:(int)b_id 
            name:(NSString *)b_name 
            code:(NSString *)b_code 
          number:(NSString *)b_number 
        location:(CLLocation *)b_location 
     description:(NSString *)b_description
        polygons:(NSArray *)b_polygons
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.buildingID = b_id;
        self.name = b_name;
        self.location = b_location;
        self.code = b_code;
        self.number = b_number;
        self.description = b_description;
        self.polygons = b_polygons;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Then this method should get all polygons and make it on map. However it doesn't show anything.

```
- (MKPolygon *)getPolygons{

    int countPoints = [self.polygons count];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D building[countPoints];

    for (int i = 0; i < countPoints; i++) {
        NSArray *splitArray = [[polygons objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        building[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[splitArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[splitArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
    }

    return [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:building count:countPoints];

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question. the code is unreadable so no one will bother to try and read it. And make your question more clear because i cant understand exactly what is your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your own definition the 7 argument to initWithID should be an NSArray*

```
- (id)initWithID:(int)b_id 
        name:(NSString *)b_name 
        code:(NSString *)b_code 
      number:(NSString *)b_number 
    location:(CLLocation *)b_location 
 description:(NSString *)b_description
    polygons:(NSArray *)b_polygons;
```

... but when you call it you pass buildingPoly ...

```
Building *building = [[[Building alloc] initWithID:[buildingID intValue] 
                                              name:name 
                                              code:code 
                                            number:number 
                                          location:tempLocation 
                                       description:description
                                          polygons:buildingPoly]autorelease];
```

... and buildingPoly is ...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D buildingPoly[countPoints];
```

which is not an NSArray.

You should really pay attention to warnings. They often are telling you fairly directly where problems are.